# Number Unread comments/posts

Tags: posts

I am having trouble getting an unread posts and comments plugin to work on my site.  I have multiple authors which I am trying to control with role scoper.  Only certain people can access certain categories.  Unfortunately none of the plugins for number of comments/posts seem to work with rolescoper defined roles; the changes still show up, but the user can't click them...

Anyway, maybe it would be easier to create a plugin where a user clicks a button next to each post they read, with a 'unread post' counter that begins only when the user registers... Hm... Is this possible? It would be a useful feature to have because then if someone doesn't want to read a post right away, they can come back to it later... maybe even tag it in a separate way so that there's a section on the site where they can read all the stuff they tagged...

Answer (score 1):

I've got a similar problem scheduled and my favorite concept so far is this:

- add a custom taxonomy 'archive', containing userid's as terms
- add an 'archived' button on each post, adding the user id to the terms and associating the post

You can then use all the taxonomy goodness to only show non-archived posts and create archive pages for each individual user...and combine it with other taxonomies.

I'll do this as a plugin, when the time comes, but it will be a while.

Comment: A+ for inventive taxonomy usage! I like this :)